# std::equal_range complains about "sequence not ordered"

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, quicksort, stl-algorithm

I need help sorting a vector of elements and subsequently processing ranges on the sorted vector.  The vector of strings is initially sorted using the default operator< predicate

Consider the following vector of unsorted strings

```
std::vector<std::string> strings = {
   "1A", "3C1", "1B", "1C1", "4D", "1C1"
}

std::sort(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::less  <std::string > );
```

after sorting this ends up lexicogarphially sorting the strings to the following:

```
"1A", "1B", "1C1", "1C1", "3C1", "4D"
```

In my case I then want to iterate through these ordered strings breaking them into ranges **[begin, end)** using the first numeric character as the value comparator - I am not sure how to do this without getting visual studio indicating "sequence not ordered"

```
"1A", "1B", "1C1", "1C1"
```

the second group should contain

```
"3C1"
```

and the final group

```
"4D"
```

I have been experimenting with **std::equal_range** using a predicate that only searches for the leading digit, but it keeps indicating "sequence not ordered" **(EDIT - this was a bug I had as I was using a comparator to equal_range that did not respect the existing order of the underlying collection)**.  I think this is because the existing sorted range (which uses std::less as a predicate is different to my predicate to extract the sub ranges is the root of the problem.  Any help on how to break this ordered list into the sub ranges would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT NOTES:**  Although the above question is answered, I would like to make the question clearer with a solid example so that others can learn where I faltered.  I oversimplified the problem I was trying to solve, The actual problem uses a class with 4 fields (1 optional) and consequently, I did not provide sufficient detail to show where I was having problems with the equal_range parameters (specifically the value I was passing into the equal range and the corresponding comparator which was used to strict weak order the elements according to this comparator - which also had to respect the existing order of the underlying collection).  As it turns out, the problem was surprisingly simple to solve - I simply had to change the explicit default **PriorityValue** constructor - taking these 4 args to a non explicit constructor where I could pass the "channel" field as a single arg constructor parameter.  As a result my call to equal_range is as follows:

```
// lambda to compare channels in ascending order 
const auto channelComp = [](const PriorityLevel& a, const PriorityLevel& b) {
    return a.getChannel() < b.getChannel();
};    

auto range = std::equal_range(gPriorities.begin(), gPriorities.end(), 1, channelComp);
// print all common channel entries
std::cout << "priorites with channel [1]" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Channel, PriorityChar, filename, [optional sequence]" << std::endl;
std::copy(range.first, range.second,
    std::ostream_iterator<PriorityLevel>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

I have a live example in **[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca599ff5b23bc9ec)** that demonstrates where I fixed the problem - I hope this is useful.

```
unsorted
Channel, PriorityChar, filename, [optional sequence]
1A[foo._dr]
3A[bar._dr]
1B[foo._dr]1
1B[bar._dr]1
1B[foo._dr]2
1B[bar._dr]2
1B[foo._dr]3
1B[foo._dr]3
1B[foo._dr]4
1B[foo._dr]5
2A[foo._dr]
2B[foo._dr]1
2B[foo._dr]2
2B[foo._dr]3
2B[foo._dr]2

sorted - ascending
Channel, PriorityChar, filename, [optional sequence]
1A[foo._dr]
1B[bar._dr]1
1B[bar._dr]2
1B[foo._dr]1
1B[foo._dr]2
1B[foo._dr]3
1B[foo._dr]3
1B[foo._dr]4
1B[foo._dr]5
2A[foo._dr]
2B[foo._dr]1
2B[foo._dr]2
2B[foo._dr]2
2B[foo._dr]3
3A[bar._dr]

priorites with channel [1]
Channel, PriorityChar, filename, [optional sequence]
1A[foo._dr]
1B[bar._dr]1
1B[bar._dr]2
1B[foo._dr]1
1B[foo._dr]2
1B[foo._dr]3
1B[foo._dr]3
1B[foo._dr]4
1B[foo._dr]5

priorites with channel [2]
Channel, PriorityChar, filename, [optional sequence]
2A[foo._dr]
2B[foo._dr]1
2B[foo._dr]2
2B[foo._dr]2
2B[foo._dr]3
```

Comment: Why not post some code instead of describing it?

Comment: the code is not in great shape, I will see if I can get it into a semi working state.  I typically send coliru links - let me see what I can do in the next half hour

Comment: At the very least, post the predicate that you use with `equal_range`.

Comment: Unfortunately the predicate something I would like to write, here is my coliru failed effort at a predicte - my predicate basically searches for the first match and not the first character match, I think that Michael Burr's predicate might work though.  If interested here is my live example - slightly different to the posed question as it has too many details that I wanted to avoid http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef44fd8b5cc45ad6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

bool initial_char_comp( std::string const& s1, std::string const& s2)
{
    if (s1.size() == 0 || s2.size() == 0) {
        return s1.size() < s2.size();
    }

    return s1[0] < s2[0];
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> strings = {
       "1A", "3C1", "1B", "1C1", "4D", "1C1"
    };

    std::sort(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::less<std::string>());

    for (auto i = strings.cbegin(); i != strings.cend(); ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (char c = '1'; c < '5'; ++c) {
        auto range = std::equal_range( strings.cbegin(), strings.cend(), std::string(1, c), initial_char_comp);

        std::cout << "range starting with '" << c << "': "; 
        for (auto i = range.first; i != range.second; ++i) {
            std::cout << *i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I will try to apply it to my live example - you can see why I did not post the live example, kudos for reading between the lines in my question - btw here is the live example that my question tries to descibe in simpler terms http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef44fd8b5cc45ad6 :)

Comment: @johnco3: the code posted at the link doesn't seem to be doing what you describe in this question - it's sorting using `std::greater<PriorityLevel>()` which involves all member fields of the class in the comparison, then does the `equal_range` operation using the same `std::greater<PriorityLevel>()` comparator.  It doesn't show the error message you ask about - it just selects and displays the single element that matches the value (as it should).

Comment: the error message I described is actually on windows and coliru uses gcc - I think the reason for the error on windows is the debug flags in stl have some safety guards to detect strict weak ordering and in the version that had that error i was using a different predicate than std::greater<PriorityLevel>() in an attempt to match the channel leading digit, anyways I tried to adopt something similar to your comparator, and it looks like it needs to construct a PriorityLevel from a numeric entity - there are some errors http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6cd57bae2f0b1d6

Comment: Thanks Michael - I posted an updated working version of my code - the problem was I was using an explicit constructor with default parameters and I should have allowed the default simple channel value to construct a PriorityLevel object.  This way we are always comparing PriorityLevels.  Code here in coliru http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca599ff5b23bc9ec